# Shorten large repetitive if else statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I was wondering what is the best way to shorten or clean up an if else statement such as this:

```
    if($(this).hasClass("home")) {
  $("body").addClass("home");
} else if($(this).hasClass("tasks")) {
  $("body").addClass("tasks");
} else if($(this).hasClass("roadmap")) {
  $("body").addClass("roadmap");
} else if($(this).hasClass("staff")) {
  $("body").addClass("staff");
} else if($(this).hasClass("timesheet")) {
  $("body").addClass("timesheet");
} else if($(this).hasClass("global-tasks")) {
  $("body").addClass("global-tasks");
} else if($(this).hasClass("deleted-tasks")) {
  $("body").addClass("deleted-tasks");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var classes = [
  "home",
  "tasks",
  "roadmap",
  "staff",
  "timesheet",
  "global-tasks",
  "deleted-tasks"
];

classes.forEach(function(className) {
  if ($(this).hasClass(className)) {
    $("body").addClass(className);
  }
});
```

Comment: Technically this is not the same.  This would potentially add multiple classes to the body.  The OP only adds one at most.

Comment: Or possibly a find() or filter()[0] to get just the first match

Comment: ooh let me try it out.

Comment: Also, small side note.  `$('body')` can be just `$(document.body)` to avoid a lookup

Comment: Also the forEach is going to change what `this` points to, unless you use an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an attribute for that element, for example, `data-body-class`.

```
$('body').addClass($(this).data('body-class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter to get the first class to add.

```js
var classes = [ 'home', 'tasks', 'roadmap', 'staff', 'timesheet', 'global-tasks', 'deleted-tasks' ];
var $thingToTest = $('.thingToTest');

$('.result').addClass(function(){
  return classes.filter(function(clazz){
    return $thingToTest.hasClass(clazz);
  })[0];
});
```

```css
.result { display: none; }
.result.staff { display: inherit; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thingToTest staff global-tasks"></div>
<span class="result">Result</span>
```